# How to deal with big aggregate roots with lots of children?

Tags: concurrency, language-agnostic, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, domain-model

I'm quite new to DDD and in our recent project we faced a problem I didn't expect.
In our domain we model the budget of a company.

Keeping things simple, the budget is a table with a bunch of rows and columns. Every department in a company has a different budget for a given year. The table could have quite a bit of rows and fixed amount of columns (basically, a name and values for every month).

Business rules our business person want to enforce are applied at a whole table level, like you can't have two rows with same name or can't edit locked table, etc.
So, after some elaboration we're decided to make a single table an aggregate in this bounding context.

**Then things started to be interesting.**

Basically, we have two problems now:

1. One table could be edited by many users at the same time, and even if someone is editing a single cell and another person edits completely different cell, from the aggregate point of view those operations are parallel edits for the single aggregate, and every one of them requires us to load the whole aggregate, apply a change, check business rules and save it back to the database.
2. Since we were using event sourcing, `load` operation becomes slower and slower with every event we commit to the database, so we decided to use a snapshot approach. We do the snapshot every X events so the load operation won't take a lot of time. But at some point we realised that after a week one of our tables had thousands of edits and the snapshot event is a giant json string like 1_000_000 characters long. Even transfering it from the database is quite slow.

At this point I started to think that making the entire table an aggregate was a mistake, and we could take a more granular approach, but I don't know any such rule in DDD I could refer to, and don't quite understand how I could enforce business rules on the entire table if I just split the aggregate to rows or something like that.

Could any of you please tell me where I was wrong and what I could do to improve the model, with references to sources I could reason about with the team?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregates are consistency boundaries, which generally means that you want to keep them small for the reasons you've encountered.

It probably makes sense to have the table be an aggregate so that table-level constraints and transitions (e.g. locked/unlocked state, for sure) can be enforced/handled.  But I'm not sure the table needs to contain all the contents of the rows: the content of each row can be modeled as its own aggregate, with the table aggregate tracking the sequence of rows (obviously, accessing the rows would be through the aggregate root).

In this approach, the table aggregate can enforce at write-time invariants that only touch the table, and the row aggregate can enforce at write-time invariants which only touch a single row.  Enforcement of invariants crossing multiple rows will have to be done via at least one projection, which means that the system cannot guarantee to reject all writes which violates the invariant.

This implies that there will almost surely eventually be a case where the desired invariant is violated (in which case, calling it an invariant is a little bit of an abuse of terminology, but bear with me...), and the system (including users, operators, etc.) will need to take a compensating action to restore the invariant.  The nature of the compensating action is a business concern: sometimes it can be automated, sometimes it's a matter of alerting for manual action.

If that's actually unacceptable, and the business demands are such that the table needs to be able to enforce invariants covering the content of multiple rows, then you are pretty well stuck with the giant table aggregate (note that you'd hit this problem even if you weren't doing DDD).

Depending on which language you're implementing in, you may find that taking advantage of the actor model and having each table be the internal state of a single actor pays off in performance terms: the actor is effectively serving as an in-memory always-current snapshot (because the actor will only process one message at a time) of the aggregate (the events since the latest persisted snapshot and the events since then only need to be replayed once to rehydrate the actor).  If the table state is a million bytes of serialized JSON, it does not seem like data size forces you to take advantage of the clustering features of some actor frameworks, so any actor model implementation should work.  [This talk explores aspects of this approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58_Ehl3oETY).

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the budgeting domain around tables and rows then you may need to reconsider your design.  I understand that many budgets are probably defined in spreadsheets, which is where the thinking comes from, but the domain terminology (ubiquitous language) would probably not be around a table/sheet and rows.

Chances are that the domain expert refers to budgeting items and probably states that an item is defined on a row and that column A is the item name and B is the January budget, etc.

The domain should be defined along the lines of the actual business language which would probably make a lot more sense and keep aggregates substantially smaller and more manageable.  I've worked on some pretty horrendous budgeting spreadsheets in my career so I can imagine trying to store the history as a serious of events would explode the storage quite quickly (even with snapshots).  Well, not even a real spreadsheet stores the data as a serious of events.  There is an undo history in the current session but that is about it.

I'm no financial guru but you probably have a budget item of sorts and then for each year you'll have a budget with the values for each month.  One budget item is quite a bit simpler than everything in one large aggregate.  The budget items can be grouped and categorised as a separate exercise.

It isn't inconceivable that I've misinterpreted your scenario but that would be my take on this.

Comment: Well, I used term "row" and "table" just to simplify things here. In the actual model we're surely using ubiquitous language you're talking about. It's all about budget items, estimates, departments, etc.
But it doesn't change the fact that we need to ensure constraints on the entire budget level, like not having same budget item twice.

Comment: OK, that changes things slightly.  Aggregates should be small and ensure consistency within the aggregate.  This means that it may be possible to move some rules to another level such as unique index database constraints.  You may even model some of these rules as a first-class citizens and make them aggregates.  What is described in your original question doesn't appear to be the most optimal design.  It definitely still sounds as though you may need to have another look at your design.  Given that you have all the events you may be able to experiment on design options using those?

Comment: Yeah, I can experiment a bit. I'm quite sure that I should reconsider the domain design, just don't know how to do it right and looking for some relevant experience here. It must be that someone had same issues before.

Comment: Rules covering collections or large sets of data are an odd thing that doesn't fit, or belong, in an aggregate.  Unique e-mail addresses is an example.  There isn't an aggregate being loaded up to ensure that an e-mail address is unique.